# Baltimora è l'unica città nordamericana col nome italianizzato?

Tags: proper-nouns

Ci ho pensato un po' di volte, e tra Stati Uniti e Canada non mi viene in mente nessuna città oltre a Baltimora che abbia il nome italianizzato. Ce ne sono?

Ai fini di questa domanda, **non contano**, se hanno:

- grafia uguale ma pronuncia diversa
- grafia diversa ma pronuncia uguale (dunque no "Filadelfia")
- non sono più usati (dunque no "Nuova York" o simili)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non so portare una fonte, ma quando tempo fa con un amico c'eravamo posti la stessa domanda, eravamo giunti alla conclusione che fossero appunto solo Baltimora e Filadelfia (c'eravamo evidentemente dati regole lievemente diverse, e poi [la pronuncia di “Philadelphia” non è proprio “Filadelfia”, ma quasi “Fluffya”](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4540)...)

**Aggiornamento:** Ho trovato anche una fonte. La rivista *Internazionale*, nelle sue [norme editoriali](http://www.internazionale.it/dalla_redazione/2015/06/25/libro-stile-internazionale), che quindi prevedono anche quali nomi stranieri italianizzare etc., menziona specificamente: «Le città degli Stati Uniti con un nome italiano sono due: Baltimora, Filadelfia».